# How to set text in center in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I want to set `Text` in center, I tried `justifyContent` and `alignItems` to center but it didn't work for me, text is displaying at the top.

LoginScreenStyles.js

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  ...ApplicationStyles.screen,
  container: {
    paddingBottom: Metrics.baseMargin
  },
  centered: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});
```

ApplicationStyles.js

```
const ApplicationStyles = {
  screen: {
    mainContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
    },
    backgroundImage: {
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0
    },
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      paddingTop: Metrics.baseMargin,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
    },
    section: {
      margin: Metrics.section,
      padding: Metrics.baseMargin
    },
    sectionText: {
      ...Fonts.style.normal,
      paddingVertical: Metrics.doubleBaseMargin,
      color: Colors.snow,
      marginVertical: Metrics.smallMargin,
      textAlign: "center"
    },
    subtitle: {
      color: Colors.snow,
      padding: Metrics.smallMargin,
      marginBottom: Metrics.smallMargin,
      marginHorizontal: Metrics.smallMargin
    },
    titleText: {
      ...Fonts.style.h2,
      fontSize: 14,
      color: Colors.text
    }
  },
  darkLabelContainer: {
    padding: Metrics.smallMargin,
    paddingBottom: Metrics.doubleBaseMargin,
    borderBottomColor: Colors.border,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: Metrics.baseMargin
  },
  darkLabel: {
    fontFamily: Fonts.type.bold,
    color: Colors.snow
  },
  groupContainer: {
    margin: Metrics.smallMargin,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    ...Fonts.style.h4,
    color: Colors.coal,
    backgroundColor: Colors.ricePaper,
    padding: Metrics.smallMargin,
    marginTop: Metrics.smallMargin,
    marginHorizontal: Metrics.baseMargin,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Colors.ember,
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
};

export default ApplicationStyles;
```

LoginScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

// Styles
import styles from "./Styles/LoginScreenStyles";

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.centered}>
          This probably isn't what your app is going to look like. Unless your
          designer handed you this screen and, in that case, congrats! You're
          ready to ship. For everyone else, this is where you'll see a live
          preview of your fully functioning app using Ignite.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write 
`justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"`
in `container` like this :

```
container: {
  paddingBottom: Metrics.baseMargin,
  justifyContent: "center", 
  alignItems: "center"
}
```

If you just want to make text center you can use `alignSelf: 'center'` in `centered`

Answer (score 4):

The style for `container` code should include this:

```
justifyContent: "center",
alignItems: "center"
```

and  **NOT**  to the `Text` itself. But if you want to make the `Text` center themselves then you should add this:

```
alignSelf: 'center'
```

To the Text styles itself. You can get an example from the official source [here for more information](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html).

Answer (score 1):

I Believe this Might Clear your concept
1. **justifyContent** : helps you to control content of View *Vertically*
 2. **alignItems**:  helps you to control content of View *Horizontally*
 3. **alignSelf** : help you make Text content *Center*.
Run Sample code for Demonstration.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", height: 200 }}>
          <Text>justifyContent works in an View vertically</Text>
          <Text>center,flex-start,flex-end</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Text>alignItems works in an View Horizontily</Text>
          <Text>center,flex-start,flex-end</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>To Make Text Center</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TouchableOpacity
           style = {styles.submitButton}
           onPress = {
              () => this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
           }>
           <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Submit </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

for text center

```
submitButtonText:{
  color: 'white',
  alignSelf: 'center'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Updated:-

```
  AnyText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 21,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }
```